# kinect depth image processing

Tags: c++, image-processing, kinect

This is my problem

Kinect is mounted on top of the room(on ceiling). Then i take a depth image of the people below the kinect.

So what i get is a top view of the people below.

Then i want to extract the heads of the people to count the number of people.

As the way i see it, this problem requires identification of LOCAL minimum regions of the image. But i coudn't figure out a way.

Can some one suggest me a way to achieve this??

Is there a OpenCV function to get local minimum regions??

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using the depth image to find the local minima? Or are you doing something with the RGB image?

Comment: i am using the depth image to find local minimum regions

Comment: is the scene, in which the people are in, static?

Comment: Assume it is static image. a static Depth image of peoples heads

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [watershed transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watershed_%28image_processing%29) to find local minima. A quick search brought up this [sample code](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/watershed.cpp) which you may want to try with OpenCV.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
Watershed algorithm requires a point to operate on. In my application i cannot give any inputs to the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a foreground-background segmentation, that separates the static background from the dynamic "foreground" (people).

Then, once you have the point clouds/depth maps of the people, you can segment them for example with some region growing ([flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)) method. This way you get the separated people which you can count or find their minimum point if you are looking for the heads specifically.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I am already doing what you are suggesting. But if two people are very close to each other, then your method will identify them as a one person.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something as simple as thresholding for near and far depths, using the **and** operation to merge the two and find the contours in the resulting image.

It's not super flexible as you're kind of hard coding a depth range (a minimum human height expected), but it's easy to setup/tweak and shouldn'be that costly computationally. Optionally you can use a bit of blur and erode/dilate to help refine the contours.

Although it has more than what I explained, you can see a demo [here](http://lifesine.eu/rec/cv3c.mov)
[image: CV threshold and contours]

And here's a basic example using OpenCV with OpenNI:

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int threshNear = 60;
int threshFar = 100;
int dilateAmt = 1;
int erodeAmt = 1;
int blurAmt = 1;
int blurPre = 1;
void on_trackbar(int, void*){}

int main( )
{
    VideoCapture capture;
    capture.open(CV_CAP_OPENNI);
    if( !capture.isOpened() )
    {
        cout << "Can not open a capture object." << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "ready" << endl;
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    namedWindow("depth map");
    createTrackbar( "amount dilate", "depth map", &dilateAmt,16, on_trackbar );
    createTrackbar( "amount erode", "depth map", &erodeAmt,16, on_trackbar );
    createTrackbar( "amount blur", "depth map", &blurAmt,16, on_trackbar );
    createTrackbar( "blur pre", "depth map", &blurPre,1, on_trackbar );
    createTrackbar( "threshold near", "depth map", &threshNear,255, on_trackbar );
    createTrackbar( "threshold far", "depth map", &threshFar,255, on_trackbar );
    for(;;)
    {
        Mat depthMap;
        if( !capture.grab() )
        {
            cout << "Can not grab images." << endl;
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            if( capture.retrieve( depthMap, CV_CAP_OPENNI_DEPTH_MAP ) )
            {
                const float scaleFactor = 0.05f;
                Mat show; depthMap.convertTo( show, CV_8UC1, scaleFactor );
                //threshold
                Mat tnear,tfar;
                show.copyTo(tnear);
                show.copyTo(tfar);
                threshold(tnear,tnear,threshNear,255,CV_THRESH_TOZERO);
                threshold(tfar,tfar,threshFar,255,CV_THRESH_TOZERO_INV);
                show = tnear & tfar;//or cvAnd(tnear,tfar,show,NULL); to join the two thresholded images
                //filter
                if(blurPre == 1) blur(show,show,Size(blurAmt+1,blurAmt+1));
                Mat cntr; show.copyTo(cntr);
                erode(cntr,cntr,Mat(),Point(-1,-1),erodeAmt);
                if(blurPre == 0) blur(cntr,cntr,Size(blurAmt+1,blurAmt+1));
                dilate(cntr,cntr,Mat(),Point(-1,-1),dilateAmt);

                //compute and draw contours
                findContours(cntr,contours,0,1);
                drawContours(cntr,contours,-1,Scalar(192,0,0),2,3);

                //optionally compute bounding box and circle to exclude small blobs(non human) or do further filtering,etc.
                int numContours = contours.size();
                vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly( numContours );
                vector<Rect> boundRect( numContours );
                vector<Point2f> centers( numContours );
                vector<float> radii(numContours);
                for(int i = 0; i < numContours; i++ ){
                    approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
                    boundRect[i] = boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]) );
                    minEnclosingCircle(contours_poly[i],centers[i],radii[i]);
                    rectangle( cntr, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), Scalar(64), 2, 8, 0 );
                    circle(cntr,centers[i],radii[i],Scalar(192));
                 }

                imshow( "depth map", show );
                imshow( "contours", cntr );
            }

        }

        if( waitKey( 30 ) == 27 ) break;//exit on esc
    }
}
```

Even if you're not using OpenNI to grab the depth stream you can still plug the depth image into OpenCV. Also, you can detect the bounding box and circle which might help filter things further a bit. Say you're setup is in an office space, you might want to avoid a column, tall plant,shelves, etc. so you can check the bounding circle's radius or bounding box's width/height ratio.

Comment: Thanks for replying. This method is also ok. But not very flexible as you have mentioned. If two or more people are close to each other, this algorithm will fail.

Comment: true, also depends on the heights and threshold values. if your thresholding around the head in a boring scenario you probably wouldn't run into blob merges, you would though if people hug/kiss/other situations where two heads are together.